# How to tell prophet to not forecast negative values

Tags: r, forecasting

using facebooks 'Prophet' package in R for forecasting. Was wondering if there is a way use it, such that it does not forecast negative values?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about Prophet specifically, but often with time series modeling, if you have a continuous measure with a lower bound at 0, you transform it prior to modeling -- e.g., log it -- model the transformed series, generate predictions, then back-transform those predictions to the original scale.

Comment: I removed the [prophet] tag - that tag is unrelated to Facebook Prophet.

Comment: @YowE3K It seems to me really correlated to prophet, why don't you think so? It is a forecasting issue related to the prophet library. :)  I came to this question through Google Query "how to set the lower boundary in prophet zero"

Answer (score 4):

Within Prophet you can set a ceiling and floor through binding columns to your sample data frame and forward dates list, however this will only bound the trend portions of the decomposed model.

To truly keep all final estimates above 0 you can either:

1. adjust your floor accordingly (not usually recommended) or
2. take the log of all your data prior to fitting the model then use predictive_samples to get a look at your posterior distribution.  You will then need to use exp() to translate that back into your original units.

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in the documentation [in this page](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/saturating_forecasts.html#forecasting-growth).

In brief, you should use "logistic" rather than "linear" growth. You must set a cap (a maximum logically possible value), and you can set a floor (if you don't set it, it will default to zero).

Assuming you have in `df` your data (a `ds` column with dates, and a `y` column with values).

You need to set a cap, for the past, as well as the future.

(I'm taking the 8.5 example figures included in the documentation... the value can change for each day, this should obviously be set to something meaningful for your case)

You can (but you don't need to) set a floor, for a minimum value.

```
df$cap <- 8.5
m <- prophet(df, growth = 'logistic')
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 1826)
future$cap <- 8.5
#future$floor <- 1.5
fcst <- predict(m, future)
plot(m, fcst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now,prophet in R provides a cap and floor,which tells prophet not to bound the floor value and cap value.
floor is the minimum and cap is the maximum.

You can refer this link for prophet.

https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/docs/saturating_forecasts.html

Comment: Didn't find that parameter @chunjin Is there like a `prophet(df, floor=0)` way?

Comment: following example:
# R
forecast <- predict(m, future)
tail(forecast[c('ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper')])